# Appcelerator Store Local Searches

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

When a button is pressed, I would like the id and the name of the button saved locally.

I am not quite sure the best way to approach this problem. Should I use appcelerator properties (http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.App.Properties) or write to a file to storage? At the moment I am using the Ti.App.Properties.setList.

Example code:

```
searchStorageName = "searchHistory";    
searchResultsArray = [];
var currentEntries = (Ti.App.Properties.getList(searchStorageName));

// Create search entry object.
var localSearchObject = {
    company_name: resultNodeCompany,
    company_id: resultNodeCompanyID,
    variation_id: resultNodeCompanyVariationID
};
// Check if existing entries, if so push current search 
// and previous searches to array.
if(currentEntries === null || currentEntries === undefined){
    searchResultsArray.push(localSearchObject); 
    Ti.App.Properties.setList(searchStorageName, searchResultsArray);
    // searchResultsArray.push(localSearchObject, currentEntries);
}
else {
    searchResultsArray.push(localSearchObject, currentEntries); 
    Ti.App.Properties.setList(searchStorageName, searchResultsArray);
}
```

I am stuck at the moment as it is inserting duplicate searches into the array. When I loop over the values to create a list in the UI it shows duplicates.

```
var currentEntries = (Ti.App.Properties.getList(searchStorageName));
var currentEntriesLength = currentEntries.length;
var getPreviousHistorySearchesArray = [];
currentEntries.forEach(function(entry, index) {
   var company_name = entry.company_name;
   var company_id = entry.company_id;
   var variation_id = entry.variation_id;

   // Create View Entry.
   createSearchHistoryViewEntry(index, company_name, company_id, variation_id);
}
```

Comment: Why you are not using   `SQLite_Database` http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Working_with_a_SQLite_Database

Comment: I have just tried using a SQLite and it works a lot better. Thanks for the tip. I am quite new to Android development.

Comment: I will write an answer please confirm it to correct , thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use `SQLite_Database` Better than local properties http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Working_with_a_SQLite_Database